# Unable to grab div class with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, findall

I am trying to grab div with class but I can't for whatever reason. There is an id but it is different for every product. How do I successfully grab < div id="feli1062" class="row mqs-prop-inner-wrap with featt">?

This is my code;

```
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

my_url = "https://meqasa.com/apartments-for-sale-in-Accra"

uClient = uReq(my_url)
page_html = uClient.read()
uClient.close()

page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")

containers = page_soup.findAll("div", {"class": "row mqs-prop-inner-wrap with featt"})
print(len(containers))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use CSS selector `div[id^="feli"]`. This will select all `<div>` tags whose `id=` begin with "feli".

For example:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = 'https://meqasa.com/apartments-for-sale-in-Accra'
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, 'html.parser')

for item in soup.select('div[id^="feli"]'):
    print(item.h2.get_text(strip=True))
    print('https://meqasa.com' + item.a['href'])
    print('-' * 80)
```

Prints:

```
3 bedroom apartment for sale at Community 25, Tema, Tema, Greater Accra Region
https://meqasa.com/3-bedroom-apartment-for-sale-in-Community 25, Tema, Tema, Greater Accra Region, Ghana-unit-1411
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2 bedroom apartment for sale at Sakumono
https://meqasa.com/2-bedroom-apartment-for-sale-in-Sakumono-unit-1385
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1 bedroom apartment for sale at East Legon
https://meqasa.com/1-bedroom-apartment-for-sale-in-East Legon-unit-1383
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2 bedroom apartment for sale at Accra
https://meqasa.com/2-bedroom-apartment-for-sale-in-Accra-unit-1408
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1 bedroom apartment for sale at Sakumono
https://meqasa.com/1-bedroom-apartment-for-sale-in-Sakumono-unit-1363
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

... and so on.
```

Comment: Hi, I am having a hard time understanding why you can use h2. I tried p and got the price but when I inspect the html, I cannot find h2 for the name and p for price. I want to use the same format to grab the date